# How to store 'for i in range' loop output

Tags: python, for-loop

**I wrote these lines to import zip file with log files in it:**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from zipfile import ZipFile
df_ht =  !unzip "/content/drive/MyDrive/HTWebLog_p1.zip"
```

**To read the log file:**

```
file = open('ex061101.log', 'r')
print(file)
```

output:

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='ex061101.log' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

```
lines = file.read().splitlines()
lines[5:6]
```

Output:

['2006-11-01 00:00:08 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET /Tulip/home/en-us/home_index.aspx - 80 - 70.80.84.76 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1) - 200 0 0']

**Now I am trying to store the loop output, but I only get the last log file (judging by the length of it):**

```
for i in range(212,229):
    lines = (open(str('ex061') + str(i) + str('.log'), 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')).read().splitlines()
len(lines)
```

**EDIT.**

**I found the solution:**

```
import itertools

lines = [] 

for i in range(212,229): 
    lines = (open(str('ex061') + str(i) + str('.log'), 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')).read().splitlines() 
output=list(itertools.chain(lines))
```

Comment: Yeah, you’re just overwriting the same variable again and again. You might want to make a list and append to it?

Comment: And, by the way, 'ex061' and '.log' are already strings,  You don't have to wrap them in `str()`.  You might even consider `f"ex061{i}.log"`.

Comment: Thank you, I did it by: 'lines = []' before loop and after loop this line: output=list(itertools.chain(lines))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop you write the variable `lines` but because it loops you over write it every time it loops which is why you are only getting the last values, a better way is to create a list and add to it every time you loop which will not over write it and store it nicely.

```
list = []

for i in range(212, 229):
   list.append(open(str('ex061') + str(i) + str('.log'), 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')).read().splitlines())
```

I havent tested the code out but should work

Comment: There is an error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'.

Your previous deleted response didn't work as well because of that error: 

AttributeErrorError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found.


But I got some ideas from that join function and eventually got this:


`lines = []`
`for i in range(212,229):`
    `lines = (open(str('ex061') + str(i) + str('.log'), 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')).read().splitlines()`

`output=list(itertools.chain(lines))`

It works.

Comment: Good to know, I didnt test the code, i just wanted to show you the list and the append aspect of it all